# Halo 4 Main Title Theme Song chant origins

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre

Link to song:

I'm wondering what language or cultural chant is being used in the recording of this song for the first minute or so. I have an idea of the region that the style of singing is coming from, but unsure exactly where.

I'm aware this isn't any specific language and was most likely custom for the game but am assuming it is based around a root culture of musical style/genre.

Can anyone help narrow down this for me?

Comment: It reminds me of the music in Planetside 2 (Vanu 'faction select music', [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFnBE6HTdFc&t=2416s)).

Comment: Similar thread [here on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/218230/discussions/0/864959088381481843/). Is it perhaps [Qawwali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qawwali)?

Answer (score 2):

There are likely a lot of influences here, but I'd suggest this is most inspired by [Bulgarian folk music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Bulgaria#Folk_music). Though you mention the first minute, it's actually at around 1:02 that tipped me off — their women's singers use extremely close harmonies that create small moments of dissonance. This kind of music comes from a long tradition of music meant to be performed outdoors (work music, festivals, etc.). It does seem that the London Bulgarian Choir is [credited in the recording of this soundtrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_4_Original_Soundtrack#Personnel)!

Similar vocals are used to create "otherworldliness" elsewhere. The very [first sounds in the Avatar (2009) soundtrack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPSBclqSBxQ) [have similar inspiration](https://bnr.bg/en/post/100103433/the-bulgarian-voice-in-james-camerons-avatar).